# Jenkins pipeline re-download maven artifacts again and again when running the pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins

I need to know why in my jenkins pipeline when creating a docker container for building a java app with maven everytime that I run the pipeline it downloads all the java artifacts/requirements again and again from the pom.xml file,, help please!

Answer (score 2):

Because the directory, where maven caches these artifacts (`~/.m2`) is inside the docker container and thus not preserved between runs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in the tutorial I followed it says that it SHOULD download the artifacts only 1 time and the next times will grab the already downloaded files, in my pipeline I use this : config "args '-v /home/bitwiseman/docker/.m2:/root/.m2'",,,  that the /home/bitwiseman/docker/.m2 diretory is empty

Comment: Good to see your code. How should we know this? But are you really running as the `bitwiseman` user within the container?

Comment: I dont know how I can check that, can you help me please?  It seems that maven download the artifacts only in the docker container but NOT locally, the /home/bitwiseman/docker/.m2 & /root/.m2 directories are empty

Comment: You could wire the local m2 repository into your container using `-v` option. That would make the downloaded artifacts being persisted on the Docker host.

Comment: Did you check the artifacts are downloaded into `/root/.m2` in container, If not, `/home/bitwiseman/docker/.m2` should be empty too. You need to map to the correct folder inside container for artifacts.

Comment: Hi, using the command "find . -name '.m2'"I found that in the home folder of jenkins "/usr/lib/jenkins" a new folder is created ".m2" BUT is owned by the user root and group root and after the pipeline is complete the folder remains empty, also another folder is created in the jenkins workspaces directory and that folder contains the downloaded artifacs, how can I tell jenkins & maven to use a specific folder? that seems to be the problem